# Is it bad practice for a REST endpoint to return different response fields based on the request?

Tags: rest

I'm developing a 'user' endpoint for my mobile app. When the authenticated user GETs another user's profile, I want to return fewer fields than when they GET their own.

Is it semantically bad/against REST principles to return a different set of fields from a REST endpoint depending on some criteria such as whether the requesting user is retrieving their data vs another user's, or should I just have 2 endpoints for the same data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally fine to return differing sets of data for the same URL based on authentication criteria. Think about a plain old web site. If you're logged in, you usually see diff contextual information than you do if you're anonymous, right? So getting more info back in the content of your response when it's the "current" user vs. a diff user is the same thing. If you really wanted to separate the fields you *could* with a sub-URL, but you definitely don't *have* to.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was against conventions and going to be confusing for clients. As it happens I think I will create 2 endpoints for clarity.